# Не работает JSONP запрос в twitter

Tags: javascript, canvas, twitter, jsonp

Программа должна выводить твитты в canvas, но, хотя адрес и запрос правильные, она не находит ссылки на ресурс. Вообще, что нужно, чтобы этот код работал?

```js
window.onload = function ()
  {
   var button = document.getElementById('Previewbutton');
   button.onclick = PreviewHandler;
  };
  function PreviewHandler ()
  {
       console.log("PreviewHandler");
    var canvas = document.getElementById("tweetshirt");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    fillBackgroundColor  (canvas,context);
    updateTweets (tweets);
    drawText (canvas,context);
    var selectObj = document.getElementById ("shape");
    var index = selectObj.selectedIndex;
    var shape = selectObj[index].value;
    if (shape=="Squares") {
      for (var squares=0; squares<20; squares++)
      {
       drawSquare (canvas,context);

      };
     };
    if (shape=="Circles") {
      for (var circles=0; circles<20; circles++)
      {
       drawCircle (canvas,context);
      };
     };

  }
  function drawCircle (canvas,context)
  {
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
   var radius = Math.floor(Math.random()*40);
   context.beginPath();
   context.arc(x,y,radius,0,2*Math.PI,true);
   context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
   context.fill();
  }
  function drawSquare (canvas,context)
  {
   var w = Math.floor(Math.random()*40);
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.width);
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random()*canvas.height);
   context.fillStyle = "lightblue";
   context.fillRect (x,y,w,w);
  };

  function fillBackgroundColor (canvas,context)
  {
   var selectObj = document.getElementById("backgroundColor");
   var index = selectObj.selectedIndex;
   var bgColor = selectObj.options[index].value;
   context.fillStyle=bgColor;
   context.fillRect (0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  }; 
  function updateTweets(tweets)
  {
    var TweetSelection = document.getElementById("tweets");
    for (var i=0; i<tweets.length; i++)
    {
     tweet = tweets[i];
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.text=tweet.text;
     option.value=tweet.text.replace("/","'");
     TweetSelection.options.add(option);
    };
    TweetSelection.selectedindex=0;
  }
  function drawText(canvas,context)
  {
   var selectObj= document.getElementById("foregroundColor");
   var index = selectObj.selectedIndex;
   var fgColor = selectObj[index].value;
   context.fillStyle = fgColor;
   context.font = "bold 1 em sans-serif";
   context.textAlign="left";
   context.fillText ("ya povelsia na etot tweet",20,40);
   selectObj = document.getElementById("tweets");
   index = selectObj.selectedIndex;
   var tweet = selectObj.options[index].value;
   context.font="italic 1.2 em sans-serif";
   context.fillText (tweet,30,100);
   context.font= "bold 1 em sans-serif";
   context.textAlign = "right";
   context.fillText("v rezultate poluchil mayku", canvas.width-20, canvas.height-40);
  }
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid black;}
```

```html
<canvas width="600" height="400" id="tweetshirt">Please upgrade your browser to use tweetshirt!</canvas>
 <form>
 <p>
  <label for="backgroundColor">Select background color:</label>
  <select id="backgroundColor">
   <option value="white" selected="selected">White</option>
   <option value="black">Black</option>
  </select>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="shape">Circles or squares?</label>
  <select id="shape">
   <option value="none" selected="selected">None</option>
   <option value="Circles">Circles</option>
   <option value="Squares">Squares</option>
  </select>
 </p>
 <p>
  <label for="foregroundColor">Select Text colour:</label>
   <select id="foregroundColor">
   <option value="Black" selected="selected">Black</option>
   <option value="White">White</option>
   </select>
 </p>
 <label for="tweets">Pick a tweet:</label>
  <select id="tweets"></select>
 
 <p>
  <input type="button" id="Previewbutton" value="Prevew">
 </p>
 </form>
 <script src="http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/wickedsmartly.json?callback=updateTweets"></script>
```

Comment: Вы на страницу https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/wickedsmartly.json ходили? смотрели что там?  написано `{"errors":[{"message":"Sorry, that page does not exist","code":34}]}` никаких твитов. так что все логично - ничего не выводит

Comment: Хорошо, как правильно нужно вставлять ссылки на твиттер в код. Это ведь не важно - что там именно будет. Допустим я хочу вывести на экран твитт любого другого пользователя, в этом canvas - как это сделать?

Comment: Вы нажимали кнопку "Выполнить код" в Вашем вопросе? Ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null" видели?

Comment: да, но я не понимаю, как это исправить. Оно ведь добавляет новый элемент - опцию.

Comment: Кто - "оно"? В Вашем html нет элемента `canvas`  с `id="tweetshirt"`, поэтому `document.getElementById("tweetshirt");` возвращает `null`.

Comment: Да нет же, есть! Это id элемента canvas

Comment: где? *(11 символов нужно...)*

Comment: Я исправил (у меня в редакторе на пк оно и было с canvas), но сути это не поменяло.

Comment: Вы нажимали кнопку "Выполнить код" в Вашем вопросе? Ошибку "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" видели?

Comment: да, видел, но я не понимаю, где. Вроде все элементы есть в html

Comment: найдите строку кода, где происходит эта ошибка